# Как Laravel вывести все записи с таблицы используя связь - один ко многим?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня таблица Пользователи и таблица img с картинками пользователей. У каждого пользователя может быть несколько картинок. Это связь 1 ко многим.

```
модель User

public function imgs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image', 'user_id');
}


модель Image    

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}

В контроллере я достаю конткретного пользователя
$users = User::find(2);

и потом в шаблоне вывожу.
```

Как вывести не одного пользователя, а всех ? У меня что-то не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить всех пользователей через модель **User**

```
$users = User::all();
```

Получить все изображения у пользователя:

```
foreach ($user->imgs as $image) {
    //
}
```

Если нужно получить всех пользователей и у них все изображения:

```
foreach (User::all() as $user) {
    foreach ($user->imgs as $image) {
        // $image->[свойства модели Image]
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно даже чуть оптимизировать получение информации о картинках юзеров: `$users = User::with('imgs')->get();`